# Can I call addEventListener Twice on the same element for the same DOM event?

Tags: javascript, dom

Can I call addEventListener Twice on the same element for the same DOM event?
I use this code for multiple JavaScript files, and it seems like they override, meaning that, the code in one of them fires, while the code in another doesn't fire.

```
(function () {
  "use strict";
  document.addEventListener('load', function (event) {

    // Code

  }, false);
}());
```

**Edit** @plalx From the jQuery source, it looks like they're using window.addEventListener('load', ...);

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
    // Use the handy event callback
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", DOMContentLoaded, false);

    // A fallback to window.onload, that will always work
    window.addEventListener("load", jQuery.ready, false);

    // If IE event model is used
} else if (document.attachEvent) {
```

Comment: No, they don't, that should just add multiple listeners to the same event. That's the whole point of addEventListener (versus e.g. window.onload = ...)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure about this, but I do not think you should attach an event handler to the load event of the document using `addEventListener`. I tested in Chrome and it doesn't work so it must not be standard. If you want to execute some code when the document is ready, you have many alternatives, but the easiest cross-browser solution would be to use `jQuery`.

However, you could do it this way as well in most modern browsers:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    alert('load!');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, the reason I'm using load, is because I need images to be loaded as well. I'm grabbing the height of my sidebar and doing some scrolling animations, so I need accurate offset heights and that only works after images are loaded.

Comment: You were right, it should be added to window: window.addEventListener("load", function () {}, false);

Comment: Also, I think jQuery wraps if (readyState === 'complete') in an interval, more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.readyState